# Start Background on display other than main

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

I have three monitors and have set the background image to a high resolution photo on tile so that it stretches across all three monitors. Unfortunately my main monitor is not the monitor on the far left so the image starts on the far right screen then continues onto the left then the middle.

Is there a way to make my main display the right monitor so I have the start menu there but have the background image start on the left monitor?